# angular4 child resolver does't wait for parent resolver

Tags: angular, angular-routing, angular-router

I have an issue with the resolver on angular 4 ( v 4.2.6 )

I have a deep routes structure like:

**MainRoute:**

```
{  

    path: 'o',
    loadChildren: './organization/organization.module#OrganizationModule'

},{

    path: 'signin',
    component: LoginComponent

},{
```

**OrganizarionModule Routes**:

```
{
    path: ':orgId',
    component: OrganizationComponent,
    canActivate: [AuthGuard],
    resolve: {
        organizations: OrganizationResolve
    },
    children: [
        {
            path: 'products',
            loadChildren: './products/products.module#ProductsModule'

        },{

            path: 'user',
            loadChildren: './user/user.module#UserModule'

        },{

            path: '',
            redirectTo: 'products',
            pathMatch: 'full'

        }
```

**ProductsModule Routes:**

```
{
    path: '',
    component: ProductsComponent,
    children: [
        {
            path: 'welcome',
            component: ProductsWelcome

        },{

            path: 'active',
            component: ProductsActive,
            resolve: {
                product: ProductsResolve
            }

        }
    ]
}
```

I need ProductsResolve ( last level children ) to wait until OragnizationResolve to be completed.

OrganizationResolve provide me a token that help me to get the products available for that organization. Is there another way to run that resolver before the others request start?

Thanks

Comment: Did you find a solution to your problem ?